# Property or method "navlink" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js

I'm having some problem with vue.js
I'm learning how to create components and I'm making some components that I want to use for a wordpress theme. I'm using the REST API to get the contents and pass the response data from axios to the UI managed by vue and vue coponents. I'm getting always this error:

```
Property or method "navlink" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property
```

This happen after I've created a new component for the nav menu, I think the code is correct but any help will be appreciated. I have the home.php file that will be used for the homepage as a template using `Template Name:` on top of the file and inside the header.php file I've removed the old menu and I've placed a vue template. I will do the same for the footer, but how I can fix errors that are caused by widgets or wordpress generated inline scripts? How I can fix my error ?

```
// this is the code of header.php 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0" id="theme-vue">
    <theme-nav v-for="nav in navData" :navlink="nav.post_title"></theme-nav>

    <script type="text/x-template" id="theme-nav">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top main-nav">
          <button class="navbar-toggler hamburger hamburger--spin" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expand="false" aria-label="<?php _e('Toggle Navigation'); ?>">
            <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
            </span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand ml-auto" href="#">
            <img src="" width="auto" height="75">
          </a>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-content" id="navbar-content">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link top" href="#">{{ navlink }}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>
    </script>
// this is the code of home.php
<?php /* Template Name: Homepage */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<uptheme-cover v-for="post in postData" :title="post.title.rendered" :src="post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url"></uptheme-cover>

<script type="text/x-template" id="uptheme-cover">
  <div class="row container-cover p-0" style="height:100vh;">
    <div class="parallax" :data-parallax-image="src"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-4">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</script>

<?php //get_footer(); ?>


// this is the footer, it will cause error in vue because of the google map iframe footer widget and wordpress footer scripts

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
  <div class="row p-0 footer">
    <?php if( is_active_sidebar('footer-map') ): ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-map'); ?>
    <?php endif;  ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-0 text-center credits-col">
      <small><?php _e('Powered by '); ?><a class="" href=""><?php _e('UpAdv')?></a></small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


// this code is placed inside the main.js file of my theme

  Vue.component('theme-nav',{
      template: '#theme-nav',
      props: {
        //navId: Number
        navlink: String,
      }
    });

    Vue.component('theme-cover',{
      template: '#theme-cover',
      props: {
        title: String,
        src: String
      }
    });

    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#theme-vue',
      data: {
        postData: [],
        navData: []
      },
      mounted: function(){
        this.getMenu();
        this.getIndex();
      },
      created: function(){
        this.initParallax();
      },
      methods: {
        initParallax: function(){
          const parallax = new universalParallax();
        },
        getMenu: function(){
// this line didn't work, I need to get the custom logo but I don't know how with REST API?
          axios.get('wp-json/theme/v1/logo').then( (response) => {
            console.log(response);
          });
          axios.get('wp-json/theme/v1/menu').then( (response) => {
            console.log(response);
            response.data.forEach( (item, i) => {
              this.navData.push(item);
            });
          });
        },
        getIndex: function(){
          axios.get('wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?slug=home&_embed').then( (res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
            res.data.forEach( (item, i) => {
              this.postData.push(item);
              console.log(item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url);
            });

          });
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the navlink under data like

```
data: {
        postData: [],
        navData: [],
        navlink:''
      }
```

Comment: ok, but I've declared it inside the component,  so it's strange I get this error

Comment: But you've declared that inside the props which is for the purpose of passing data from parent to child component (you can google the difference between props and data with respect to Vue)

Comment: I know that I can also use the `data()` function and return an object for the components, but also if I change the code the error will remain.

Comment: seems the initialisation part of your code needs a tweak

Comment: it's a vue warning.

Comment: is the theme-nav component loaded/initialised? are you able to check that?

Comment: Yes and I need to fix the v-for for the content because with the actual code the loop will duplicate the markup. I'm testing using `data(){}` inside my components but the error still remain. what's the correct way to do this?